# Redirect .php to extensionless and make url without .php

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

I dont really know too much about Rewrite in apache, but there is problem with my .htaccess file.

the original .htaccess is

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-_.]*)$ /profile.php?id=$1 [L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

# Redirect non-www to www:
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]


# Unless directory, remove trailing slash
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# Redirect external .php requests to extensionless url
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(.+)\.php([#?][^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# Resolve .php file for extensionless php urls
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ $1.php [L]


ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
```

The first rewrite is for vanity url, another is redirecting non www to www and after that .php to extension less and redirecting .php file to extension less,

Problem i am facing is, if i request www.domain.com/ttt.php and if ttt doesn't exist then it redirects me to http://www.domain.com/profile?id=ttt.php 
Also, i want the rewrite to be for php files not other type, Say if i have ttt.png file and i open www.domain.com/ttt it opens the image rather than showing 404 error.

Similarly happens with other type of files. It opens .txt file first if the names are common.

Thanks for any changes to this, seriously i don't want to mess my site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-_.]*)$ /profile.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Needs to be at the very end.

And this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Needs the `[L]` flag and needs to replace `RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ $1.php [L]`. Then you can duplicate this one and replace `.php` with `.png`, and `.txt` and every other extension you want to handle, in the order of preference:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -Multiviews

RewriteEngine on

# Redirect non-www to www:
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]


# Unless directory, remove trailing slash
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# Redirect external .php requests to extensionless url
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(.+)\.php([#?][^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# add extension if the php file exists:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]

# add extension if the png file exists:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.png -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.png [L]

# add extension if the txt file exists:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.txt -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.txt [L]

# add extension if the html file exists:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [L]

# etc.

# finally, route to profile.php if all else fails
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-_.]*)$ /profile.php?id=$1 [L]

ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
```

Since you're routing to `profile.php`, in the `profile.php` script, you'll need to redirect to `/404.html` if the `id` param doesn't exist (meaning the URI that got routed needs to be a 404).